# java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to get a Long variable from an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I will be very brief, I am making an attendance control application for teachers.

In the main activity the list of groups is loaded and each one has a button to edit its information. (I use recyclerview and adapters)

This happens when you click the Edit button:

**In GroupAdapter Class>OnBindViewHolder**

```
int lastPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    long idGroupUP = mGroups.get(lastPosition).getId_group();
    holder.ibtnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clicsListener.editClic(lastPosition, idGroupUP);
        }
    });
```

**In MainActivity Class**

```
@Override
public void editClic(int position, long idGroup) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditGroup.class);
    intent.putExtra("idGroup", idGroup);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);
    resultEditGroup.launch(intent);
}
```

**In EditGroup Class**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_group);
    editGroupViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(EditGroupViewModel.class);
    idGroup = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("idGroup");
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Once the group id is obtained, all the information is loaded from the database.
So in the Crashes section of the Play Console I can see that 7 users have been affected by the following issue, This is what I read in PlayConsole:

```
    Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3477)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3620)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2183)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:241)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7617)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:941)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.os.Bundle.getLong(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
  at com.lista.asistencia.EditGroup.onCreate (EditGroup.java:86)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7817)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7806)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1328)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3452)
```

I don't see why this would happen, since the EditGroup.class is only initialized from that one button. I also did not see the need to put the rest of the code of my Adapter because it does not make sense, since the long variable `idGrupoUP` cannot be null, so the error is not there either.

I have 1000 active users and I have good reviews (in the Play Store), I have done tests on several devices and they do not present that problem, so I do not understand what happens to those 7 users to whom that has happened. I hope someone can help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter how it happens, you need to check for nulls in this line:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getLong("idGroup")
```

It's telling you that `getIntent().getExtras()` is `NULL` in some specific circumstances. It's impossible to tell when it could actually happens because you didn't post your code for the `EditGroup` class, so we have no way of knowing where and how you're calling that line. But right away I can give you at least 3 possibilities:

1. If someone is using a custom launcher app, they can create shortcut directly to any activity in your app. So, if they're launching `EditGroup` for some reason, no extras would ever be sent, and so you'll get a `NullPointerException`
2. Again, without seeing your code, I'm just guessing, but there could be a navigation issue. For example, if you launch any activity from your `EditGroup` class, it's possible that upon returning back to the `EditGroup` class, it tries to read the intent extras, and at that point they would be `NULL`
3. I don't know what your Manifest looks like, but if the `EditGroup` activity has any intent filters, then it can be launched using those filters. And, again, the extras could easily be NULL

So, as I said, the bottom line is that you have to check that line for NULLs or surround it with try/catch

Comment: Your answer is very complete!
I did not consider it necessary to include the first few lines of code, but I have already edited the question and included them.
Anyway thanks to your answer I see that there are many reasons for which it can have a null value, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The null object is the Bundle got from `getIntent().getExtras()`.
The `startActivity`'s process may be injected and retrofited by system, you can pay attention to the device brands and versions which get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to check nullability of `getIntent().getExtras()`

For better convenience, convert the java code to Kotlin and
use following as an example :

```
intent.extras!!.getInt(EXTRA_ROOM_ID)
intent.extras?.getInt(EXTRA_ROOM_ID) ?: 0
```